# Как получить подобную структуру?

Tags: php, база-данных

Поставили задачу разработать подобное,но никак не получается подойти к правильному построению такой структуры. В админке начал кое что но всеравно не совсем получается,так как вложенность блоков большая.Вот наброски в бд,если нужно структуру в бд изменить просьба подсказать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мне не понятен момент каким образом генерируются так блоки,как будто не зависят друг от друга.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставите мне в квартиру хорошие окошки, тогда ладно уж помогу.

Comment: А можно описание к задаче сделать более осмысленное, а то понятие "как сделать такую структуру" можно трактовать как хочется. Что Вы подразумеваете под словом "такую"?

Comment: Аналогичную данной.Есть  4 типа окон,каждое из них делится на подтипы,и в свою очередь подтипы так же делятся на определенные опции,при этом в хтмл каждый подтип или опция генерируется отдельным блоком как будто не связано никак с родителем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При проектировании БД исходите из сущностей и их свойств. Так же, если есть какие-то характеристики, которые могут быть изменены и быть описаны отдельно, надо вынести их в отдельные таблицы.

В данном случае я вижу две сущности, это сама рама и окна, которые входят в раму. При этом у окна всегда может поменяться набор материалов, профилей и декоров. А у пакетов их направление открытия.

Хотя я не знаю точных условий и Вы их так и не предоставили. Но если исходить из вышесказанного, то примерная структура БД могла бы выглядеть как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что касается HTML генерирования блоков, там скорее всего логическая ошибка в некоторых местах и сайт просто надеется на адекватность заказчика. К примеру, что он не выберет раму в четыре окна и только одним окном.

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет!